# How to run a React.js effect when a 3rd party library is loaded using useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to create a `<Drift>` component that mounts the Drift chat service:

*Drift.js*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Drift (props) {
  const [drift, setDrift] = useState(undefined)

  // Evaluate the drift script once
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.getElementById('drift-script').innerHTML
    window.eval(script)
  }, [])

  // Poll for drift availability
  useEffect(() => {
    const poller = setInterval(() => {

      if (window.drift) {
        setDrift(window.drift)
        clearInterval(poller)

        console.log('setDrift(fn) called')
      }
    }, 500)

    return () => clearInterval(poller)
  }, [])

  // Configure the drift widget once
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('drift depended effect triggered:')
    console.log(typeof drift)

    if (drift) {
      console.log('drift is defined')

      drift.config({
        messages: {
          welcomeMessage: 'Your code is being generated!'
        }
      })

      drift.on('ready', function (api) {
        console.log('drift ready')

        api.widget.hide()

        api.widget.show()
        api.showWelcomeMessage()
      })
    }
    else {
      console.log('drift is undefined')
    }
  }, [drift])

  return (
    <div>
      <script
        id="drift-script"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `
          "use strict";

          !function() {
            var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
            if (!t.init) {
              if (t.invoked) return void (window.console && console.error && console.error("Drift snippet included twice."));
              t.invoked = !0, t.methods = [ "identify", "config", "track", "reset", "debug", "show", "ping", "page", "hide", "off", "on" ], 
              t.factory = function(e) {
                return function() {
                  var n = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
                  return n.unshift(e), t.push(n), t;
                };
              }, t.methods.forEach(function(e) {
                t[e] = t.factory(e);
              }), t.load = function(t) {
                var e = 3e5, n = Math.ceil(new Date() / e) * e, o = document.createElement("script");
                o.type = "text/javascript", o.async = !0, o.crossorigin = "anonymous", o.src = "https://js.driftt.com/include/" + n + "/" + t + ".js";
                var i = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                i.parentNode.insertBefore(o, i);
              };
            }
          }();
          drift.SNIPPET_VERSION = '0.3.1';

          drift.load('DRIFT_ID');
          `
        }}
      />

      { props.children }
    </div>
  )
}
```

The idea is that the effect is run once `window.drift` becomes defined. However, the effect is only run once -- when window.drift is undefined.

The complete log is:

```
drift depended effect triggered:
Drift.js:30 undefined
Drift.js:51 drift is undefined
Drift.js:20 setDrift(fn) called
```

How can I create a reference to window.drift that causes the effect to be executed once it is defined?

Comment: did you check that `setDrift(window.drift)` line is executed (using a breakpoint or `console.log('was here')`?

Comment: It seems to work like you expect. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vqprox?editors=0011 As long you are calling `setDrift(window.drift)` then that second effect should definitely run.

Comment: @Aprillion I did; I updated the source code and included the log in my original question

Comment: When I change `setDrift(window.drift)` to `setDrift(true)` the depending effect starts to trigger. Why does it not trigger when drift is set to a function?

Comment: I don't see any reason why the `useEffect(..., [drift])` didn't execute during 2nd render - are you sure there is no `useMemo` and no conditional rendering like `{!window.drift && <Drift />}` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Drift client as a script in the head tag.

**Working Example**

[image: Edit kind-shape-1wus8]

---

To get it work, add the contents of the script given by drift as text in a file. Then, load that as a script in a `useEffect` by creating a script tag.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  script.innerHTML = drift;
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  return () => script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
}, []);
```

---

Also if you want this to be available across your app, you can just add it as an inline script tag in your template index html file, which is used by webpack.

Answer (score 1):

If it was possible to import a library, that would be preferable:

```
import Drift from 'drift'
```

If not, I would suggest to run the imperative code not related to React in `index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
...
!function() {
  var t = window.driftt = window.drift = window.driftt || [];
  ...
ReactDOM.render(...)
```

Or execute the script from a separate file in `index.html` (in `public` folder if using create-react-app):

```
<body>
  <div id='root'>
  <script src="drift.js"></script>
</body>
```